# ExtJS - How do I access app.json data on runtime?

Tags: javascript, extjs

On ExtJS 6.2 we can define the application name and version on the `app.json` file, is there a way to access these values on runtime?

Comment: Ext.getApplication().getName() - not sure regarding the version prop. I would suggest to consult the manual: ie https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.3/classic/Ext.app.Application.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Ext.manifest` to get all kind of information about your application. Simply type it to the console of browser and see what's inside. Application name will be in `Ext.manifest.name`.